# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582 throw err

Tags: node.js, npm, modulenotfounderror

I'm getting following Console Error. Error : Cannot find module

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NodeJsProject\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
    code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
```

requireStack: []

I try to delete node_modules and package-lock.json directory
and re-installed them again by runing npm install.

But it didn't work.

Comment: Solution: my parent folder name was myProjet&01 and i changed it to myProject and it fixed the issue. If the file name contains any special characters(even parent folders) try updating it. In my case, it was & after i removed  it works.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you get this problem in react js,after deleting package.lock.json and node modules..and again install node modules using command
eg:-npm install
it will install dependencies.. after that check in the package.json file..
check in the dependencies of script. there if you see in the start key value is
"start":"node scripts/start.js"..   then change that in to the "start":"react-scripts start ..
then install the react-scripts using command (npm install react-scripts)
then run the application using command(npm start)..then that will work in react js..

step-1:-
npm install
step2:-
inside package.json file check script tag
{
"start":"react-scripts start"
}
step-3:
if react scripts are not there .install the react-scripts module using commnad (npm react-scripts).
step4:-
run the application using(npm start)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).